# Jackrabbit - why does search excerpt contain all node properties concatenated?

Tags: lucene, highlighting, jackrabbit

When I perform a jackrabbit (version 2.2.9) search and I call get row.getValue("rep:excerpt()") the returned string is just all the properties (excluding jcr: properties) concatenated. How do I control this? eg. If I have a property called "description" containing "bla foo bla" when I search for "foo" I would like to see rep:excerpt() return part of just the description.

I tried creating an index config (and I deleted my repository between tests) in an attempt to control what properties were indexed, to no avail.

Workspace.xml...

```
<SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
  <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
  <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
  <param name="excerptProviderClass" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.DefaultHTMLExcerpt"/>
  <param name="indexingConfiguration" value="${wsp.home}/indexing_configuration.xml"/>
</SearchIndex>
```

indexing_configuration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration SYSTEM "http://jackrabbit.apache.org/dtd/indexing-configuration-1.0.dtd">
<configuration xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0">
  <index-rule nodeType="nt:teneoNode">
<property>description</property>
<property>input</property>
<property>key</property>
<property>comment</property>
  </index-rule>
</configuration>
```

Thanks.

Ted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the `ExcerptProvider` ([Javadoc](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.2/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/query/lucene/ExcerptProvider.html)) implementation which is responsible for the `rep:excerpt()` functionality in the `SearchIndex` element of you `workspace.xml` file:

```
 <param name="excerptProviderClass" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.DefaultHTMLExcerpt"/>
```

You might need to plugin in your own implementation for you specific needs.

There is also some - unfortunately rather old - information on the [Jackrabbit Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/ExcerptProvider).

Comment: Thanks, seen all that. Was hoping I could configure the DefaultHTMLExcerpt without having to write my own.

Comment: After some messing around I have come to the conclusion that its not worth writing our own ExcerptProvider, just too much hassle. You have to look up the node then go through the properties to find the one that matched your search term which is what SHOULD already be done for you. The built in stuff is only good for finding a node that matched your query, it doesn't have any other information.

Best solution for us is to implement Lucene ourselves so we can optimize the index format and easily return the relevant info in the search results.